# How do I add the timestamp from Firestore to the my variable

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How do I add the timestamp from the firebase database to the my variable? I can't found:(

I need this: DD.MMM.YYYY or DD.MM.YY

**My Output:**

```
2020-01-13 01:55:49.283 16131-16131/com.berkanaslan.instagramclonefirebase I/System.out: Timestamp(seconds=1578781711, nanoseconds=126000000)
2020-01-13 01:55:49.283 16131-16131/com.berkanaslan.instagramclonefirebase I/System.out: Timestamp(seconds=1578780607, nanoseconds=174000000)
2020-01-13 01:55:49.283 16131-16131/com.berkanaslan.instagramclonefirebase I/System.out: Timestamp(seconds=1578776024, nanoseconds=136000000)
2020-01-13 01:55:49.283 16131-16131/com.berkanaslan.instagramclonefirebase I/System.out: Timestamp(seconds=1578769230, nanoseconds=435000000)
2020-01-13 01:55:49.284 16131-16131/com.berkanaslan.instagramclonefirebase I/System.out: Timestamp(seconds=1578769218, nanoseconds=442000000)
2020-01-13 01:55:49.284 16131-16131/com.berkanaslan.instagramclonefirebase I/System.out: Timestamp(seconds=1578769204, nanoseconds=442000000)
```

**My ArrayList in Activity:**

```
ArrayList<String> userImgDateForProfile;
```

**OnCreate:**

```
    getDataFromFirestoreForProfile();

userImgDateForProfile = new ArrayList<>();
        //RecycleView
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.profileRacyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        profileRecyclerAdapter = new ProfileRecyclerAdapter(userEmailForProfile, userCommentForProfile, userImgUrlForProfile,userImgDateForProfile);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(profileRecyclerAdapter);
```

**getDataFromFirestoreForProfile():**

```
public void getDataFromFirestoreForProfile() {
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    String profileCheckID = firebaseUser.getEmail();

    CollectionReference collectionReference = firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts");
    collectionReference.whereEqualTo("User_EMail", profileCheckID).orderBy("Upload_Date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

            if (e != null) {
                System.out.println(e);
                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, e.getLocalizedMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (queryDocumentSnapshots != null) {
                for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments()) {
                    Map<String, Object> data = snapshot.getData();

                    String comment = (String) data.get("User_Comment");
                    String userEmail = (String) data.get("User_EMail");
                    String imgdataurl = (String) data.get("User_Image_Url");
                    String imgDate = (String) data.get("Upload_Date").toString();

                    userCommentForProfile.add(comment);
                    userEmailForProfile.add(userEmail);
                    userImgUrlForProfile.add(imgdataurl);
                    userImgDateForProfile.add(imgDate);

                    System.out.println(imgDate);

                    profileRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }


        }
    });

}
```

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// You can cast your Firestore document's Timestamp field into a Timestamp object
Timestamp dataTimestamp = (Timestamp) docSnapshot.get("timestamp_field");

// Retrieve a Date from the Timestamp
Date dataDate = dataTimestamp.toDate();

// Define the format your Date should be in
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MMM.yyyy", Locale.getDefault());

// Create a String in the defined format using your Date
String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(dataDate);
```

You can check out https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat for more information on formatting with SimpleDateFormat.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
  Date date = new Date(1578781711L * 1000);
  DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz");
```

The output:

```
11 Jan 2020 10:28:31 GMT+00:00
```

To get what you want DD.MM.YYYY make `SimpleDataFormat` like this :

```
SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy")
```

The output:

```
11 Jan 2020
```